# Can I let users pay with credit card on the Android Mobile Payments Library?

Tags: android, paypal, website-payment-pro

I'm building an Android App to make chained payments and want users to be able to pay by credit card if they don't have PayPal accounts.
I've followed the instructions here:
https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_MPL_Developer_Guide_and_Reference_Android.pdf

and it works great but only shows PayPal login screen. I cant find where to put the SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole bit that shows a pay with CC option though? I've turned in on in my sandbox -> website payments pro -> preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTIONTYPE=SOLE would go in the SetExpressCheckout call.